# How to animate an image onto the screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, uiimage, screenshot

I am new to Objective-C and I want to let a screenshot made with

```
CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
...
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
...
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

"fly in" (rotating and stoping in random angle) inside an own image container, looking like a small photo (shadow, white border). how could I realize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a vague question - and your code shows only how you are getting the screen image - here's a general answer.

- Put the image on a CAImageLayer
- Add a border or a shadow or whatever other chrome you need to your image layer (or on another layer underneath it)
- Use Core Animation to animate this CAImageLayer to whatever position or state you want it to be in.

Comment: seems like a good point to start. I will try that out... thnx!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it with OpenGL ES.

Here is a great project which provides generic base OpenGL ES view transition class.
https://github.com/epatel/EPGLTransitionView

There are several predefined transitions, you can take as an example https://github.com/epatel/EPGLTransitionView/tree/master/src

Demo3Transition actually shows how to rotate the screenshot
https://github.com/epatel/EPGLTransitionView/blob/master/src/Demo3Transition.m

You can view available transitions in actions if you launch DemoProject.